# Infinite loop after realloc

Tags: c

a hobbyist here, so sorry for the nooby question.

I've been trying to do K&R ex. 1-13 but with dynamic memory allocation and pointers.
K&R ex. 1-13: "Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging."

Because I'm using Windows, I replaced EOF that is used in the book to 'q' in main loop condition, the latter must be seperated from the intended last word with a whitespace.

Everything is working well until the block statement with realloc is not executed. So if the input is "stackoverflow is the best q" without the quotes, bars correctly appear as the number of words (4) can be stored in the originally allocated memory (5 blocks). However, if input consists more than 5 words, the result is an infinite loop. Could someone please shed some light on what am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void exit_if_null_ptr(int* x) {
  if (NULL == x) {
    printf("memory allocation error!");
    exit(-1);
  }
}

static void draw_histogram_horizontal(int* length_of_words, int word_count) {
  for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
    int tmp = *(length_of_words + i);
    while (tmp) {
      printf("*");
      tmp--;
    };
    printf("\n");
  }
}

static void histogram_word_length(void) {
  char c = '\0';
  int word_count = 0, // also offset to length_of_words pointer
     inside_word = 0;
  size_t mem_blocks = 5;
  int* length_of_words = (int*)calloc(mem_blocks, sizeof(int));
  exit_if_null_ptr(length_of_words);
  while ('q' != (c = getchar())) {
    if (' ' == c || '\t' == c || '\n' == c) {
      if (inside_word) {
        inside_word = 0;
        word_count++;
        if (word_count == (int)mem_blocks) {
          mem_blocks += 5;
          length_of_words = (int*)realloc(length_of_words, mem_blocks);
          exit_if_null_ptr(length_of_words);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      inside_word = 1;
      *(length_of_words + word_count) += 1;
    }
  }
  draw_histogram_horizontal(length_of_words, word_count);
  free(length_of_words);
}

int main(void) {
  histogram_word_length();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If realloc fails then length_of_words will be assign NULL, but the original value was not freed.

Comment: `realloc` also seems incorrectly sized: it takes a number of *bytes* to increase the allocation to, while calloc takes a number of *blocks* of the specified size. Mixing them seems like a terrible idea, you should probably use `realloc` in both cases. An other issue is that `realloc` *does not zero its memory*, so the additional memory is uninitialized, and reading from it is UB.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue: `echo 'stackoverflow is the very best a q'| ./a.out` gives me 6 bars.  Please update question with input that triggers error.

Comment: `realloc` does not zero the new memory.

Comment: The code also doesn't handle `getchar`'s error condition.

Comment: @AllanWind the error condition for realloc doesn't matter much in this case: if realloc fails (which is unlikely) the program immediately exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because the new size passed to `realloc()` is incorrect: `length_of_words = (int*)realloc(length_of_words, mem_blocks);` should be:

```
length_of_words = (int*)realloc(length_of_words, mem_blocks * sizeof(int));
```

Note that it is safer to use the type of array object to avoid problems when changing it to something else or copying the code for a different type:

```
length_of_words = realloc(length_of_words, mem_blocks * sizeof(*length_of_words));
```

Furthermore, the newly portion of the array is uninitialized, and your algorithm relies on it being initialized to 0.

```
size_t new_size = mem_blocks + 5;
length_of_words = realloc(length_of_words, new_size * sizeof(*length_of_words));
exit_if_null_ptr(length_of_words);
while (mem_blocks < new_size)
    length_of_words[mem_blocks++] = 0;
```

There are other problems in the code:

- `char c = '\0';` should be `int c;`
- you should test for `EOF` to avoid an infinite loop at end of file:

  ```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != 'q')
  ```

Comment: The code also has undefined behaviour because the new memory is unintialized, reading it is UB.

Comment: wrt `int c`, also the condition should probably be `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`, that way it doesn't prevent using the `q` character (in that case Ctrl-D ends the program).

Comment: Your second point is incorrect though, `length_of_words[word_count]` is incremented once per character.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, big thanks to chqrlie and Masklinn!